# Cisco ICM PG for Avaya G3 and ASAI Error C_BADMSG

Tags: cisco, avaya

I am testing to establish a link from Cisco ICM using CVLAN with Avaya PG and this is the error i am getting, i have checked all configuration from my MAPD but can't find why this error occurs.

Log from Avaya PG:

> 20:30:01:393 PG1A-pim1 Trace: RECV Socket Failure: asai_errno=-13
>   socket=1284 errno=0 GetLastError()=0 ret=-1
>
> 20:30:01:393 PG1A-pim1 Socket connection failure to 10.10.10.222. Recv
>   Ret=-1 AsaiErrno=C_BADMSG Errno=0 GetLastError()=0
>
> 20:30:01:393 PG1A-pim1 ASAI Link 0: SHUTDOWN initiated